# Adding Bearer token in Web performance tool Visual Studio 2013 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing

I have recorded a site that I want to monitor its performance in Web Performance tool Visual Studio 2013. In my site for each request I am sending Bearer token. So, how can I add the bearer token in web performance tool or the recorder holds the Authorization header by default.

[image]
I am very new to this tool and I searched many sites regarding this but I could not found the solution. Help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: What is a "bearer token"? Where in the HTTP(s) request would you put it? What is the relevance of the screenshot? I cannot see anything that says missing bearer token. It just shows that every request failed, plus you have highlighted the second request so the screenshot does not give any useful details of the first request to fail.

Comment: Bearer token is nothing but Authorization token to add in every request. yes, i want to put it in HTTP headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the context (right click) menu of the request that needs the token, select "Add header". Use the properties panel of the newly added header to set the required name and value of the token.

If the same header field is required on more than one request you can copy the whole header entry and paste it into another request. (The copy and paste commands are not fully implemented across web tests. In some places the Control-C and Control-V commands work, in other places context menu copy and paste commands work, in others both styles work. Just do some experimenting.)

If the token is required in all of the requests and there are lots of requests in the web test it may be easier to create a `WebTestPlugin` and set the header in the `PreRequest` method. Use a statement based on:

```
e.Request.Headers.Add("the header field's name", "and it's value")
```

Comment: I have go through your answer. I was facing same issue. From your answer copy & paste option is working fine. But as you were suggested another approach that add webtestplugin. now i dont have such a knowledge that how to add webtestplugin? can you please guide me?